# My c++ header in eclipse dosen't work

Tags: c++, eclipse

I made a simple header in which i have a function which adds two ints but it the compiler doesn't recognize it even after i link the header with my project and i include it:
in alx.h:

```
#ifndef ALX_H_
#define ALX_H_
#include <iostream>
int add(int a,int b);



#endif /* ALX_H_ */
```

in alx.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "alx.h"
using namespace std;

int add(int a,int b) {
    return a+b;
}
```

in test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "alx.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numb;
    numb=add(15,5);
    cout << numb;
    return 0;
}
```

here are the properties of test : https://i.stack.imgur.com/y11Lt.jpg

Comment: why isn't `alx.cpp` in sources?

Comment: Why do you include iostream everywhere? How do you build your alx project, and how did you specify that test depends on it?

Comment: @SebastianRedl Hes probably a student and his teacher hasn't explained him anything about iostream and std, cut some slack... Or self learning

Comment: @NoamRodrik I mean no attack. It's just the Socratic method. Instead of telling him that the include is unnecessary, I ask why he does it, in the hope that he will take a few minutes to research it.

Comment: I removed #include <iostream> from alx.cpp and alx.h because i realized it is unnecessary but it hasn't helped, i still get the error message "undefined reference to `add(int,int)'

Comment: did you include the header/source location in the eclipse directory?

Comment: @KostasRim When i created the header it i set its source as alx.cpp so i think i did

Comment: @LordNoob Try these 2 things: a) go to your project and add the header and the sources on your project. Now all your files should be visible in the IDE. Try to compile, if the problem persists then you have not set the include directories(http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.ptp.pldt.doc.user/html/includes.html)

Comment: @LordNoob Look at projects and files - `alx` and `test` are distinct projects, so there is no `alx.h` and `alx.cpp` in your `test` project. Add these files to the `test` project and be a happy man.

Comment: @BlackMoses thanks, now it works, but  is it possible to make a header that can be accessed across multiple projects?

Comment: @LordNoob Even if your header could be accessed by many projects, the `cpp` file also must be accessed, or there will be undefined reference to definitions. That's why there are libraries instead of plain `.cpp`, that encapsulate `.cpp` files, so then the can be added to projects `dependant path`. Adding header file to project should be possible by adding it to `include path` in any IDE (sorry, I don't use eclipse). So, when you add header in `include path`, and your `.cpp` in form of `.lib` to your `dependant path` then you get what you are looking for.

Comment: @LordNoob But for starters I would suggest to simply copy these files to your projects.